# How to allow an empty foreign key in Django?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm very new to Django so this may be the dumbest question ever.
I have 2 models set up in django; 'Class' and 'Profile'.

The 'Profile' class has a foreign key that references 'Class'. When creating a profile on the front end I am unable to leave the form blank as ("Profile.group" must be a "Class" instance.). I want to be able to create a profile that doesn't have to belong to a class.

```
class Class(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    # a few other things that don't matter

    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # a few other things that don't matter
    group = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

and in form.py

```
class ProfileRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # a few other things
    group = forms.CharField(max_length=5, required=False)
```

If there is anything important that I've missed out please let me know, it's my first time posting here so I don't know what the standard is.

Comment: The `group` should not be a `CharField`, but a `ModelChoiceField`, you can however use a *widget* that implements a searchbar, for example with `django-autocomplete-light`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to create a profile that doesn't have to belong to a class.

That is already the case. By making the field nullable, you can just pass `None` to it, and then it does not relate to any class.

The `group` in your form however, should not be a `CharField`, but a `ModelChoiceField`. The way you communicate with the user is determined by the *widget* you attach to it. You can for example use a *widget* that implements a search bar, for example with [**`django-select2`** [Django-doc]](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or [**`django-autocomplete-light`** [Django-doc]](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html). `django-autocomplete-lightweight` allows to fetch the records through AJAX, making the burden on the render engine less.

For example we can install `django-select2` in the virtual environment with:

```
pip install django_select2
```

Next in the `ProfileRegisterForm` we, can specifyh the widget as:

```
from django_select2.forms import Select2Widget
from app.models import Class

class ProfileRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Class.objects.all(), widget=Select2Widget
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```